# Preg_replace returning empty post

Tags: php

```
$input = array(
    '@\[(?i)br\](.*?)@si',
    '@\[(?i)b\](.*?)\[/(?i)b\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)i\](.*?)\[/(?i)i\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)u\](.*?)\[/(?i)u\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)img\](.*?)\[/(?i)img\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)code\](.*?)\[/(?i)code\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)s\](.*?)\[/(?i)s\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)webs=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/(?i)webs\]@si',
    '~\[(?i)color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/(?i)color\]~s',
    '@\[(?i)h1\](.*?)\[/(?i)h1\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)h2\](.*?)\[/(?i)h2\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)h3\](.*?)\[/(?i)h3\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)h4\](.*?)\[/(?i)h4\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)h5\](.*?)\[/(?i)h5\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)h6\](.*?)\[/(?i)h6\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)ul\](.*?)\[/(?i)ul\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)ol\](.*?)\[/(?i)ol\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)quote\](.*?)\[/(?i)quote\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)a\](.*?)\[/(?i)a\]@si',
    '~\[(?i)bcolor=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/bcolor\]~s',
    '~\[(?i)t=(.*?):c=(.*?):p=(.*?):w=(.*?):s=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/t\]~s',
    '@\[(?i)tr\](.*?)\[/(?i)tr\]@si',
    '@\[(?i)td\](.*?)\[/(?i)td\]@si',
    '~\[(?i)span=(.*?):c=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/span\]~s',
    '~\[(?i)pre\](.*?)\[/pre\]~s'
);

$output = array(
    '<br/>',
    '<b>\\1</b>',
    '<i>\\1</i>',
    '<u>\\1</u>',
    '<img src="\\1">',
    '<code>\\1</code>',
    '<s>\\1</s>',
    '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>',
    '<span style="color:$1;">$2</span>',
    '<h1>\\1</h1>',
    '<h2>\\1</h2>',
    '<h3>\\1<h3>',
    '<h4>\\1</h4>',
    '<h5>\\1</h5>',
    '<h6>\\1</h6>',
    '<ul>\\1</ul>',
    '<ol>\\1</ol>',
    '<quote>\\1</quote>',
    '<a>\\1</a>',
    '<span style="background-color:\\1;">\\2</span>',
    '<table border="\\1"cellspacing="\\2"cellpadding="\\3"width="\\4"style="background-color:\\5;">\\6</table>',
    '<tr>\\1</tr>',
    '<td>\\1</td>',
    '<span style="background-color:\\1;color:\\2;">\\3</span>',
    '<pre>\\1</pre>'
);

$post="[b]i love stackoverflow[/b]";

echo preg_replace($input,$output,$post);
```

The code was working fine before, but my code is now returning an empty string. I read that `preg_replace` is deprecated, but how do I use    `preg_replace_callback` with my code? Thanks.

Comment: please format your code, it will encourage people helping you

Comment: Am using a java phone pls i dont knw how to format it

Comment: I improved the formatting in your code, but, you're still going to have to explain what the actual problem is; specifically, what you changed that caused it to stop working, and what the expected and actual results are.

Comment: That is a pretty complicated call to `preg_replace` you're making, so you probably want to remove pieces until you find the one part that's not working, and then having identified it, fix it.

Comment: It is bbcode script. I changed nothing. It just stoped working    `echo preg_replace($input,$output,$post);`     i changed nothing. It jx stoped

Comment: Hate to say it, but, it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks.. I have already reduced the INPUT and OUPUT array before i came here

Comment: Ok..  Thanks so much. Let me go over it agahin  I will get back to you

Comment: Thanks so much@jbafford .. It was my fault. Not this code. Thankx

Comment: `preg_replace` is *NOT* deprecated, `ereg_*` functions are. Feel free to use all `preg_*` functions.